# Why won't querySelectorAll select all of my elements?

Tags: javascript, dom

In this example, the querySelectorAll selects `td` elements 2 through 4:

```
document.querySelectorAll("td + td");

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, it's going to select all `td` elements greater than or equal to 2.

But in the following example, `'div'` is not selecting both of my `div` elements when I use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').style.color = 'red';

<div>foo</div>
<div>bar</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LYK3e/1)

Why doesn't querySelectorAll work in this basic scenario?

Comment: [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll. It returns a `NodeList`, which acts like an array.

Comment: I already checked that but couldn't understand and now seeing the answer below I got concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) returns an array-like object ([NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)), so you can't set the property of all matched elements like that (like jQuery). You have to iterate over them:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++){
    divs[i].style.color = "red";
}
```

Note: this differs from [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), which by contrast always returns a single element.

You can write a helper function like:

```
function qsa(selector, styleProperty, value){
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

    for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++){
        divs[i].style[styleProperty] = value;
    }
    return divs;
}
```

Usage:

```
var divs = qsa('div', 'color', 'red');
```

Comment: without loop can I use something like this? divs[].style.color="red"

Comment: Thank you very much. But I'm still in a confusion that why this works without requiring a loop http://jsfiddle.net/tMrbA/

Comment: That works because you're creating a jQuery object from the NodeList, and jQuery automatically loops over elements without the need for you to do your own loop;

Comment: oh! I didn't care about jquery there.